# Masstransit analyzers raising an error with IEnumerable properties

Tags: masstransit

We have a message

```
public interface MyMessage 
{
  IEnumerable<int> MyProperty { get; }
}
```

```
await _publishEndpoint.Publish<MyMessage>(new { MyProperty = new List<int>()}});
```

When Masstransit.Analyzers is installed compiling project throws following error on publish statement:

*[MCA0001] Anonymous type does not map to message contract 'MyMessage'. The following properties of the anonymous type are incompatible: MyProperty.*

Comment: This seems more like a bug report than an actual question.

Comment: Maybe. I thought that this might be resolved somehow . I'll try and submit a bug report.